# How to use Oracle analytic partition by with "greater than" expression?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Oracle documentation says I can use:

```
select avg(id) over (partition by <expression>) from table1;
```

For example this goes well:

```
select avg(id) over (partition by id) from table1;
```

But if I use "greater than" expression I got failure ORA-00907:

```
select avg(id) over (partition by (id > 3)) from table1;
```

Where syntax of expression is documented? Can I use "greater than" expressions to partition record set?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The syntax is explained in the manual (where else?): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#i81407

Comment: Why don't you simply add a `where id > 3` to your statement?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name maybe because it does something completely different?

Comment: @JensSchauder: different than what? Wiz has not explained what he/she is really after.

Comment: different than a partition by clause in an analytic function. IMHO the OP made it clear that he want the analytic function partioned in to groups: those with id >3 and the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that Oracle SQL does not properly support Boolean expressions. But a case expression should work where you return 1 if id>3 and 0 otherwise.

```
case when (i >3) then 1
else 0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To use these sorts of expressions, I always put the variable in a subquery:

```
select avg(id) over (partition by whichid)
from (select t.*, (case when id > 3 then 'low' else 'high' end) as whichid
      from table1 t
     ) t
```